# Can "Gewehr" and "Waffe" be used interchangeably?

Tags: meaning

It seems that "Gewehr" can mean gun, but also specifically rifles.  Can "Gewehr" be used more generally to mean all guns, or does it only mean rifles specifically?

Comment: Gewehr (gevär) is something resembling a rifle. Waffe could be any weapon. Atomwaffe for example atomic weapons.

Comment: Certainly not in composite words. *Luftwaffe* and *Luftgewehr* are very distinct things.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

*Gewehr* today typically denotes any gun that has a long barrel (as opposed to a pistol). Rifles, machine guns, even shotguns.

And no, it is not the generic term for *gun*, that would be *Schusswaffe*.

The word *Gewehr* itself was actually part of the language *before* guns were even invented - It used to mean anything that could be used as a means of long-range defense before you got into a melee fight, so it included battlements, walls, towers, barricades, whatever (The [Grimm](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GG13661#XGG13661) has an extensive explanation on that). Over time, the meaning focused on guns but still anything that would not apply to melee battle.

Comment: Add to that, "Waffe" would be akin to *weapon*, with the regular p>f correspondence

Comment: Since *Wehr* only means defense, there must be a particular language historic reason. Imaginably, pistols were an innovation taken from Italian, contrasting with the long builds. A Pistol is generically called "Handfeuerwaffe". In the same way, a "Schusswaffe" should, but practically doesn't denote an archers bow. In contrast to a bow, guns involve gun-fire, but we do not say "Feuerwaffe", though the term does seem to exist, to my surprise.

Comment: @vectory Why do you say a bow isn't a *Schusswaffe*? If you asked me to name one, I'd probably name a type of gun first, but if you asked me what type of weapon a bow was, I'd definitely say *Schusswaffe*. The crossbow is another such case.

Comment: @Phillip, it's not even a weapon, nowadays, but a "Sportgerät" or a historical artifact.

Comment: @vectory Sorry, you're thinking of Bundes*wehr* or Feuer*wehr*, but the historic term is, rather specifically, a long knive with one sharp edge, the defence weapon of a free man, but not a nobleman or for war. And "Feuerwaffe" separates the gun from the crossbow, both of which are "Schusswaffen". Also in modern legal terms, where the latter are qualified by the ability to be kept charged without effort, and released by a trigger. A bow is not *per se* regarded as a weapon, but only if actually used as such.

Comment: I may be splitting hairs, but I have the impression that a shotgun (=*Schrotflinte*) would not be called *Gewehr* in spite of usually having a long barrel. Only a weapon firing bullets and with a long barrel, so a rifle or a machinegun (=*Maschinengewehr*) or an assault rifle (=*Sturmgewehr*) would qualify, but pistols, revolvers, shotguns would not. +1 for mentioning the barrel length though.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen A shotgun would definitely be a *Gewehr*

Comment: I accept your word. But I'm a bit surprised.

Comment: I'm testing this with Google translate (Finnish-to-German), and have yet to find a translation of a type of weapon not shooting bullets that would include *Gewehr*. Adding *Jagdgeweher* (a hunting rifle) to the list. Anyway, my experiment probably suffers from some built in bias :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen look up „Schrotgewehr“

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen actually, if you look into the history of the word, it used to mean anything that could act as a means of defense - before guns were invented, a „Gewehr„ could even be a wall or tower.

Comment: I have been educated. Danke.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: In the conceptual cosmos of the average German, a shotgun is a type of "Gewehr" that fires many small bullets ("Kugeln") rather than just a single one. And even so, rayguns with long barrels in scifi movies are also called "Lasergewehr" or similar.

Comment: Thanks, @O.R.Mapper. I now recognize that my first searches were biased by words loaned from German. First Swedish loaned this word in the form *gevär* that Finnish mutated into *kivääri*. The Swedish WP page includes all long barreled firearms, the Finnish WP page does not, but it does give more information about the etymology (in accordance with what tofro says above). As an example of a word with a shared root it mentions Stau*wehr* - a type of a dam or [weir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weir). Again, confirming tofro's last comment.

Comment: @tofro Es ist vielleicht ein altes Wort, aber das Seitengewehr ist auch ein Gewehr und meint Degen, Säbel und Bajonette. Das zählt als *melee*, würde ich sagen.

Comment: @Philipp ... was die meisten Menschen (auch Muttersprachler), die das Wort zum ersten Mal hören, wahrscheinlich ausgesprochen wundert. Von daher ist es eher die Ausnahme, die die Regel bestätigt.

Comment: @tofro Da bin ich anderer Ansicht (was natürlich irrelevant ist). Es gibt ja auch verwandte Begriffe wie das Wehrgehänge. *Sich wehren* bedeutet ja nicht, Schusswaffen zu tragen, und das gilt auch für *bewehrt* sein. Das Konzept auf *Gewehr* zu übertragen ist nur eine kleine Transferleistung ;)

Comment: @Philipp Als *das Gewehr* werden u.A. auch in der Jägersprache die Hauer eines Keilers bezeichnet. Trotzdem würde ich das nicht zur Regel erheben, und es vor allem nicht versuchen, das jemandem zu erklären, der die deutsche Sprache lernen will. Es ist nunmal so, dass *Gewehr* zu 99,9% eine Schusswaffe mit langem Lauf bezeichnet. Ausnahmen gibt es, sie mögen interessant sein, aber für einen Lerner nicht hilfreich.

Comment: Da hast du recht. Ich bin bloß darüber gestolpert, dass du in deinem Hinweis auf die **historische** Nutzung den Nahkampf ausschließt.

Answer (score 14):

### Waffe = weapon

This can be a gun, a bomb, a missile, and many other things that are made to hurt or kill people. 
Depending on the context, a *Waffe* also can be anything that can be *used* to hurt or kill people, independent of what it was made for - so a screwdriver, a baseball bat, or a box cutter can also be *Waffen*.

---

### Gewehr = rifle, long gun

A *Gewehr* is any gun with a long barrel, i.e. something that shoots bullets, but not a pistol.

---

### Schusswaffe = gun

Schusswaffe (literally: *shoot-weapon*) is the German word for any weapons that can be used to shoot bullets.

Comment: German language (and law) makes a clear distiction between a *weapon*, made for the purpose (a gun, a spring knive, a crossbow), and sth. that is just *used as* one in a given case (screwdriver, axe, bow and arrow ,..).

Comment: However, a "Seitengewehr" is a bayonet - a cold weapon, not  a gun at all. Also note that if you look at the word Gewehr without context, it seems to mean "defense-stuff" without any mention of shooting :)

Comment: @rackandboneman That is a historical development. "Gewehr" used to denote anything you use for defense, even before guns were invented. Today, it (nearly) exclusively refers to guns. "Seitengewehr" is not a common usage today and even most native speakers will be confused to learn it's no gun at all.

Comment: @Karl: I somewhat disagree concerning language. A statement like "Eilig sah sie sich nach einer Waffe um und nahm einen der Schraubenzieher von der Werkbank." sounds completely idiomatic and it is clear that the screwdriver *is* her weapon (because she intends to use it as such).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper The meaning is a bit context driven. If you'd ask someone on the street to name weapons (Waffen), they wouldn't come up with a screwdriver or vase. But you can use both as a weapon which then makes it one in that context. A totally clear form of your sentence would be "Eilig sah sie sich nach etwas um, das sie als Waffe benutzen könnte, und..." but that is far too long to be used in an action sequence, so language adapts to the context and is contracted.

Comment: Why are you discussing? I clearly wrote **»Depending on the context«** in my answer, and you all argue, that it depends on the context if you can call a screwdriver a weapon. But that is *exactly* what I've written. So, what is the purpose of your discussion?

Comment: @rackandboneman: A "Seitengewehr" it is not a gun, but it is put *on* a gun, hence the name.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Very probably not. Hunters denote the set of tusks on a boar as *Gewehr* - and those are not mounted on guns, as far as I know. A *Seitengewehr* is carried on the belt (on the *side* of the body) and a defense weapon that is put onto the gun - It would possibly have the same name if you put it on a spear. (Military language is weird, sometimes). See http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GS25565#XGS25565

Comment: @tofro: From wikipedia: A bayonet is a knife, sword, or spike-shaped weapon designed to fit on the end of a rifle's muzzle, allowing it to be used as a spear. It is actually **sideways aligned** with the muzzle of the gun. I assume that is where it got the name. That is why e.g. a dental [Bajonettzange](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/38/Extraktionszange_20100113_011.JPG) is called that way: because of the form. The active part is shifted sideways and parallel to the shaft.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis You might not be aware, but *Seitengewehr" is much older than guns - It just denotes weapons carried on the belt (knife, dagger, sword,...), as opposed to *Obergewehr* which denotes weapons carried on the shoulder, like bows and crossbows (or, these days, machine guns). Thus, a *Seitengewehr* is not necessarily a bayonet (in most cases, it is, however, as soldiers rarely carry swords these days).

Comment: @tofro: Yeah, I guess you are right.